# Make tag follower count availabe in SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Today I liked to get a list of tags sorted by followers. I found [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/53688/trying-to-see-if-tag-followers-is-available) where someone tried to get similar data already, but it seems it was not successful. I didn't find a related property as well, so I think it's not possible right now to get such a list.

Therefore my request i to make this data available and add a `FollowerCount` value to `Tags`.

Monitoring this value over time might give additional insight to language or technology trends in comparison to pure question/answer count.

Comment: This should probably be posted on Meta.SE, where there are a lot more [data-explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new/data-explorer?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&pageSize=50) questions posted, and (I think) some employees might be monitoring the tag.

Comment: @BilltheLizard but that would be a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176321/get-favorite-count-for-tag)

Comment: @rene nice find, another feature request that has no response at all from the team. :-(

Comment: it was at 3 votes when I arrived. Can't blame them if there is so little interest in it... @davidism

Comment: I checked the [StackAPI](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag) but that info isn't available there either

Comment: @rene Ok, I guess nobody is monitoring that tag, then. ;)